# Monitoring various Nagios? Alternative to Coffeesaint

Tags: monitoring, nagios

In our company, we have one nagios for each of our clients, to offer them a 24x7 monitoring service. Currently, we are using Coffeesaint to have a "central monitoring display" were all alarms about hosts and services are shown. But it does not work perfectly all the time with more than 3 nagios configured and having to read large "status.dat" files. So we're thinking about changing from Coffeesaint to any other tool that does "the same".

I would like to know if you know any other tool that does the same but is more complete or has more options than Coffeesaint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using the [Distributed Monitoring](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/distributed.html) function of Nagios? if you want a nice gui you can add [Birdseye2](https://www.monitoringexchange.org/wiki/Addon:Birdseye2) on the central server.

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to give up Nagios, I highly recommend [Zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com/). With it you would just need one service and can create multiple groups for each client. You can create multiple users with different levels of access to any number of groups you want.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend [Pandora FMS](http://pandorafms.com). With Pandora FMS you would just need one tool to see at a central monitoring display and monitoring all the hosts That you need through SNMP, ICMP, TCP, WMI, software agents etc ... You can create multiple users With Different levels of access to any number of groups you want.

Using a tool you can have all the features that gives you Nagios + Coffeesaint